# SignalR only sending messages sporadically on azure

Tags: javascript, c#, reactjs, azure, signalr

I've a small react web app receiving data from an azure mobile app back-end. The back-end is a simple REST API using C#'s ApiController. The clients should be informed about specific changes in the back-end done by other clients. Therefore I'm using signalr. Running all on localhost while developing works fine and all messages are sent correctly. Deploying the back-end to azure results in only some messages are sent. No specific type of message just every 3-6th time it should be sent it will be.

Some snippets - how I try to do it:

To Keep it really simple:

Hub looks like:

```
public class PostHub : Hub {}
```

It's registered like follows (to allow cors)

```
app.Map("/signalr", map =>
{
    map.UseCors(new CorsOptions
    {
        PolicyProvider = new CorsPolicyProvider
        {
            PolicyResolver = context =>
            {
                var policy = new CorsPolicy();
                policy.Origins.Add("*");
                policy.AllowAnyMethod = true;
                policy.AllowAnyHeader = true;
                policy.SupportsCredentials = true;
                return Task.FromResult(policy);
            }
        }
    });
    var hubConfig = new HubConfiguration { };
    map.RunSignalR(hubConfig);
});
```

Sending the message from within a controllers method looks like (simplified):

```
pubic async Task<IHttpActionResult> ChangeSomething(string id)
{
    ... update some data in the back-end if allowed and so on...

    // result = changed data from the back-end having an Id property.

    IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<PostHub>();
    context.Clients.All.InformToUpdateDataFor(result.Id);

    return Ok(result);
}
```

The client (js) uses the npm package signalr version 2.3.0. And as already mentioned it seems to correctly receive messages (if they are sent ;)

What could be the Problem? I read about some other similar problems here but they seem to be different, because it is not really deterministc when a message is sent and when it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

I've to blame myself...

I was playing around with horizontal scaling of the web app. So I configured to have x instances. I had forgotten that I increased the instance count and I didn't setup signalR to use a service bus. This resulted in the problem, that the specific instances of the web app didn't know about the connections of the other instances and therefore I only got sporadically responses...

If someone else has this problem just setup a service bus and tell signalR to use it...